# Composite or aggregation in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

kind of a beginner in Meteor and MongoDB and I'm running into one issue which might or not be solved by meteor-composite-publish.
I have a collection of events like this:

```
{category:A, path:A1, content:"", createdAt:"11/10/2015"}
{category:A, path:A1, content:"", createdAt:"11/11/2015"}
{category:A, path:A1, content:"", createdAt:"11/12/2015"}
{category:A, path:A2, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
{category:A, path:A3, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
{category:B, path:B1, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
{category:B, path:B2, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
{category:B, path:B3, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
```

I want to be able to do 2 things:

1. Publish the latest events created for each path, together; the path are dynamic, so I cannot use a predefined query
   In my case should be:

   ```
   {category:A, path:A1, content:"", createdAt:"11/12/2015"}
   {category:A, path:A2, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
   {category:A, path:A3, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
   {category:B, path:B1, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
   {category:B, path:B2, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
   {category:B, path:B3, content:"", createdAt:"..."}
   ```
2. Publish the latest events created for a specific category.

Probably some kind of aggregation would be nice, but don't know what to use.. Any advice for me?

Comment: Is there a collection of *paths* as well? In that case publish-composite would be useful.

Comment: There's no Paths collection. Yet. Would it help if I add one? How would I use publish-composite?